# How to use navigation with orbeon forms created with form builder?

Tags: orbeon

I'm new to orbeon, and trying to implement navigation on my forms created on the form builder based on user responses, i read the documentation and it says that the navigation is handled with the page flow, but how can i achieve that if those forms are stored on the database not in a file structure?

Comment: What type of navigation would you like to do? Could give us an example thereof?

Comment: Adrian, did you manage to implement the type of navigation you were aiming for? If not, could you provide us with more details on what you want to do in a comment?